# update column values based on other column value and previous values in sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

[image]

In the above table i want the output mentioned in days column based on the value column.

When val column is not null then day column should set to zero, and when val column is null value then it should set to 1 and when contionus null values are present the day column should increment 1,2 eg.

also here need to consider the partition based on material and machinenumber.
and order by year,month and date.

i have tried the sql queries and spark sql to use partition but it is not working beacause it is partitioning the val column and the null value incremented by 1 using the row_number function.

i want the output like this
When val column is not null then day column should set to zero, and when val column is null value then it should set to 1 and when contionus null values are present the day column should increment 1,2 eg.

also here need to consider the partition based on material and machinenumber.
and order by year,month and date.

Comment: Please provide your sample data as a text table rather than as an image, which we can't easily copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can build groups of rows that contain a non-null value optionnaly followed by nulls with a window count, then enumerate the rows within the groups.

```
select t.*,
    row_number() over(
        partition by material, grp
        order by year, month, date
    ) - 1 cnt_consecutive_null_values
from (
    select t.*,
        count(val) over(
            partition by material 
            order by year, month, date
        ) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```